# Can someone explain this joke about the fine-structure constant and Pauli?

Tags: soft-question

I was once told this joke:

> In Dec 1989 Physics Today ,page 9, David Gross wrote "...One of the best of the many Pauli jokes tells of Pauli's arriving in Heaven and being given, as befits a theoretical physicist, an appointment with God. When granted the customary free wish, he requests that God explain to him why the value of the fine-structure constant, alpha = e^2/(hbar*c), which measures the strength of the electric force, is 0.00729735 ....
>   God goes to the blackboards and starts to write furiously. Pauli watches with pleasure but soon starts shaking his head violently...."

and I didn't laugh because I didn't understand. I found the joke online recently, but I still don't understand. Could someone explain the meaning behind it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no actual physics content.

Comment: physics culture/history is of interest to others in the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pauli was not noted for suffering fools gladly, or indeed at all. If he thought you were talking rubbish he would tell you so, and in terms that left you in no doubt about his low opinions of your physics.

In particular, if you were giving a presentation and Pauli thought you were talking rubbish he would start shaking his head. This became so well known that watching Pauli's head became a popular pastime in seminars if Pauli was in the audience.

So the joke is that having died and gone to heaven Pauli is about to tell God that he/she/it is talking b******s.

The joke would be funny mainly to people who have been on the receiving end of Pauli's tongue, or have witnessed some other poor unfortunate in that position. I suppose it's funny in the sense that one might look to Heaven and think *OK God, it's your turn now!*.